# Connect multiple accounts on Zapier CLI app

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I'd like to connect two different accounts with one Zapier app. I've seen other apps support this but there doesn't seem to be any mention of this in the documentation or be any example apps that do this.

Looking at the [auth documentation](https://zapier.github.io/zapier-platform-cli/#authentication), there doesn't seem to be an option to pass in multiple authentication handlers:

```
const App = {
  // ...
  authentication: authentication
  // ...
};
```

How can I get my app to have the user connect to two separate accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Good question, I'll try and clear the confusion here.

You do not need to build out any functionality to handle multiple user accounts for your app. Zapier will do this for you. All you need to do is specify how your app authenticates.

Once you push the app, you can go to the connected accounts tab, search for your app and connect multiple user accounts.

[image: connected accounts tab]

One can also add another user account while using the app in a Zap (that rhymed!). Click on connect account and complete the auth.

[image: Connecting accounts in a Zap]

Hope that helps!

Comment: I need this to be streamlined into the actual app for the end-user. This won't do that right?

Comment: If I understood this right, the end user of your app on Zapier should be able to add multiple accounts. If that is the case, when your app is published, they will be able to do this.